# Null Pointer Exception in First Android App

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to write my first Android app, and I'm having trouble.  I wrote a simple Java program to find the factors of a number provided by the user, and I'd like to port it over to Java.  I have an XML file for the interface, which seemed to run OK until I added the first Java class.  Now it won't run, and log.cat says that there's a null pointer exception.  So far, I only have stubs, but it seems like it should run OK with what I've done to this point.  I'm including the log.cat text, but I'm too new it this to make much sense out of it.

There may be more than one problem.  After adding the Java file I began to get run-time errors right away, but I don't think they were null pointer exceptions.  I think that started when I made changes to fix what was already causing problems.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the Java file:

```
import android.app.Activity;  <br>
import android.os.Bundle;  <br>
import android.widget.Button;   <br>
import android.widget.EditText;  <br>
import android.widget.TextView;  <br>

public class AndroidFactoringActivity extends Activity {

    // Instance Variables
    EditText userNumber;
    Button factorButton;
    TextView resultsField;
    int factorResults;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    factorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.factorButton);
    userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNumber);
    factorResults = 1;
    resultsField.setText(String.valueOf(factorResults));
}   
}
```

Here is main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/askField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ask"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/factorButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/click" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultsField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tell"
        android:textSize="24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the log.cat results:

```
 03-31 23:58:53.579: D/AndroidRuntime(2804): Shutting down VM

    03-31 23:58:53.589: W/dalvikvm(2804): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)

    03-31 23:58:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2804): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.dave_b.factoring/net.dave_b.factoring.AndroidFactoringActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at net.dave_b.factoring.AndroidFactoringActivity.onCreate(AndroidFactoringActivity.java:26)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)

    03-31 23:58:53.650: E/AndroidRuntime(2804):     ... 11 more

    03-31 23:58:53.679: I/dalvikvm(2804): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3

    03-31 23:58:53.679: E/dalvikvm(2804): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

    03-31 23:59:57.629: I/Process(2804): Sending signal. PID: 2804 SIG: 9

    04-01 00:07:36.129: D/AndroidRuntime(3040): Shutting down VM

    04-01 00:07:36.129: W/dalvikvm(3040): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)

    04-01 00:07:36.139: E/AndroidRuntime(3040): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.dave_b.factoring/net.dave_b.factoring.AndroidFactoringActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at net.dave_b.factoring.AndroidFactoringActivity.onCreate(AndroidFactoringActivity.java:26)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)

    04-01 00:07:36.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     ... 11 more

    04-01 00:07:36.199: I/dalvikvm(3040): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3

    04-01 00:07:36.199: E/dalvikvm(3040): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

    04-01 00:07:40.329: I/Process(3040): Sending signal. PID: 3040 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a null pointer because you didnt intialise the variable resultsField (you just declared it) .

As you used

`userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNumber);`

you must even initialise the reference resultsField.
This can be done using

`resultsField= (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.resultsField);`

in the `onCreate()` after the statement `setContentView()`

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you to accept any answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left side of every anwer.

Answer (score 2):

```
resultsField.setText(String.valueOf(factorResults));
```

`resultsField` is `null` and you are trying to set value on null.

```
resultsField= (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.userNumber);
```

Get textview instance before setting value, otherwise `resultsField` will be `null` and all operations on `null` reference results in `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the userNumer and resultsFiled as follows

userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNumber);
resultsField= (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.resultsField);